# Converter array que virou string em array denovo

Tags: javascript

Uso esta funçao para transformar palavras em bytes,

```
function bytesFromWords (string) {
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8);
        bytes.push(char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

se eu usa-la assim, transformando o resultado final em string como eu poderei fazer ela voltar a ser uma array novamente?

```
bytesFromWords('teste soPT').toString();
```

Comment: Você quer reverter a operação de `bytesFromWords` (retornando à string original), ou gerar uma array onde cada posição é o valor de um byte?

Comment: Quero reverter para virar a array de bytes novamente depois de ter feito virar string @bfavaretto

Comment: Seria isso [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59278/5082)?

Comment: eu tentei isso, mas nao virou a array igual como era.. @SilvioAndorinha

Comment: Perdão, tenta novamente.. tinha um erro no código no ponto e virgula.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha sim sim, mas ele vira uma array se letras e nao numeros.. faça o teste

Comment: Ainda não entendi, você quer reverter as operações `charCodeAt`, `char >>> 8` e `char & 0xFF` ou não?

Comment: Você quer que ele volte a ser "teste soPT" ou quer ele em números no formato array?

Comment: @bfavaretto veja o exemplo que montei aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/g2a9LfyL/ eu quero que ele volte a ser como o primeiro.. veja a diferença usando split.

Comment: Você quer obter uma array assim: `['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e', ' ', 's', 'o', 'P', 'T']`? Se for isso, não é possível, pois sua função descarta informações. Se for só transformar `"0,116,0,101,0,115,0,116,0,101,0,32,0,115,0,111,0,80,0,84"` numa array com esses números, é só usar `split` como na resposta abaixo e como no seu próprio jsfiddle (que funciona).

Comment: @bfavaretto a primeira impressao do console resulta numa array de numeros.. a segunda resulta naquela array em forma de string e a terceira resulta numa array de numeros em forma de string, eu quero que eles se torne uma array de numeros e nao numeros em forma de string, se observar eles estao até em ""

Comment: Pronto, consegui.. agora entendi o que você queria, da uma olhada na resposta.

Comment: Ah, perdão, eu não tinha reparado. Também postei uma resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Use o comando `split()` junto com o `for()`

```
var string = bytesFromWords('teste soPT');

array_novo=[];
array_splitado=string.toString().split(',');
for(i=0;i<array_splitado.length;i++)
{
   array_novo.push(parseInt(array_splitado[i]));
}
console.log(array_novo);
```

### [Exemplo vivo](http://jsfiddle.net/e0wygmqp/)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar primeiro um `split` para transformar a lista em array, e depois um `map` para gerar uma nova array transformando cada string dentro dela em número:

```js
function bytesFromWords (string) {
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8);
        bytes.push(char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}

var lista = bytesFromWords('teste soPT').toString();
var strArray = lista.split(',');
var numArray = strArray.map(function(item) {
  return parseInt(item, 10);
});
console.log(numArray);
```

Seria muito mais bonito se desse para fazer `var numArray = lista.split(',').map(parseInt)`. Porém, o `map` passa o índice do elemento como segundo parâmetro, enquanto o `parseInt` recebe a base da conversão como segundo parâmetro, o que estraga o resultado. Para possibilitar uma sintaxe dessa, você precisaria criar uma função que fizesse o `parseInt` com o segundo argumento fixo:

```
function myParseInt(num) {
    return parseInt(num, 10);
}
// Aí sim:
var numArray = lista.split(',').map(myParseInt);
```